# Defining multiplication, exponentiation and floor of logarithm in the ordinals.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logarithms, ordinals

While studying theoretical computer science the following problem about ordinals came up:

> Define the operations of multiplication $(n*m)$, exponentiation $(n^m)$ and integer part of the logarithm in base 2 $(\lfloor log_2 n \rfloor)$ over the ordinals (successor).

I think I could define multiplication and exponentiation in a way similar to what we do for the sum. However, I would like some help defining the integer part of the logarithm in base 2.

Having previously defined the sum of ordinals as:

> $\alpha + 0 = \alpha$
>
> $\alpha + (\beta+1) = (\alpha + \beta) + 1$
>
> $\alpha + \beta = sup\{\alpha + \delta \ | \ \delta < \beta\} $ if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

multiplication was defined as:

> $\alpha * 0 = 0$
>
> $\alpha * (\beta+1) = (\alpha * \beta) + \alpha$
>
> $\alpha * \beta = sup\{\alpha * \delta \ | \ \delta < \beta\} $ if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

and exponentiation was defined as:

> $\alpha^0 = 1$
>
> $\alpha^{(\beta+1)} = (\alpha^\beta) * \alpha$
>
> $\alpha^\beta = sup\{\alpha^\delta \ | \ \delta < \beta\} $ if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to define $\lfloor log_2 n \rfloor$? I have a guess that I may need to start by defining $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$, but I am not sure how I would do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think $\left\lfloor \frac{\omega}{2} \right\rfloor$ makes sense. If you've defined $2^\alpha$, then you can form the set $\{\beta \mid 2^\beta \leq \alpha\}$...

Comment: Thanks @aschepler . So as far as I understood it would be enough to put $\lfloor log_2 n \rfloor = \{\beta \ | \ 2^\beta \leq n \}$ and I would not even need to divide into cases according to whether $n$ is a limit ordinal or not, right?

Comment: Thanks, @aschepler. If you want, you can write your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@aschepler gave me the hint I was looking for in his comment, which I am writing as an answer so I can accept it. There is no need to consider $\lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. Instead, since we have already defined exponentiation, we should consider the set $\{\beta \ | \ 2^\beta \leq n \}$.